# Git - File changed but i keep seeing nothing to commit, working directory clean

Tags: git, heroku

I have a `sitemap.xml` file in my git repository (in a subfolder called site: `site/sitemap.xml`).

Whenever I change this file if I go ahead and do:

`git add .` on the root folder, then `git commit -am "change done"` I keep getting the message `nothing to commit, working directory clean`.

I've checked my `.gitignore` both the global and the one specific to the project `.git/info/excludes` and nothing listed in there.

Any ideas why this file is not being tracked?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `site` also a git repo?

Comment: Yes it is - I have my other HTML files in there and they are all tracked ok.

Comment: Then you need to run `git add .` and `git commit` in `site`.

Comment: when u edit the file `sitemap.xml` and then fire a command `git status` what is the output?

Comment: It says `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: Make sure you actually track this file `git ls-files`. It should list your file.  Also, try to delete this file and see if git catches it. If not - it is definitely ignored. If it does - it depends what exactly do you change there. Spaces? Tabs? Line endings?